# Immersive mode navigation becomes sticky after volume press or minimise-restore

Tags: android, android-fullscreen

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        this.getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(getSystemUiFlags());
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    private static int getSystemUiFlags() {
            return View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION;
    }

}
```

After first start

[image: After first start]

After volume buttons pressed or after recent apps pressed twice

[image]

I saw QuickPic app doesn't have this bug. I wonder how they omitted it.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The following code works for me:

```java
public void updateUI() {
    final View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    decorView.setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener (new View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility) {
            if ((visibility & View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN) == 0) {
                decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
                        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
                }
            }
        });
}
```

And called the listener on `onCreate` and `onResume` methods:

```java
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    updateUI();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    updateUI();
}
```

Comment: Does this fix still have the effect of the black bar during volume change?

Comment: @Peter Brooks I have tried this, and even though it fixes the immersive mode, the navigation bar is indeed black for the second it is visible.

Comment: it doesn't work with me 
in case of appearing keyboard

Comment: its does still show for a second, but at lease my content is not moved so that helped me a lot :)

Comment: Had to call it in onResume. Thanks

Comment: Exquisite. Thank you gent

Comment: Works perfectly on Android N. Thanks!

Comment: Relevant documentation: https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/visibility.html

Comment: setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener needs fitsSystemWindows  set to false in order to work

Answer (score 29):

My solution is to set the UI-Visibility flags in three places:

1. When getting the focus
2. In onResume
3. In the OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener listener

The third solved my problem. The others might not be needed, but I left them.
This is what is looks like:

```
  private void setupMainWindowDisplayMode() {
    View decorView = setSystemUiVisilityMode();
    decorView.setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener(new OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener() {
      @Override
      public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility) {
        setSystemUiVisilityMode(); // Needed to avoid exiting immersive_sticky when keyboard is displayed
      }
    });
  }

  private View setSystemUiVisilityMode() {
    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    int options;
    options =
        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
      | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
      | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
      | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION // hide nav bar
      | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN // hide status bar
      | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;

    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(options);
    return decorView;
  }
```

setupMainWindowDisplayMode() gets called in onCreate().

Comment: The third option alone isn't enough. After a lot of testing, I noticed that the `OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener` doesn't always fire. I solved this by adding the first option, but to be sure I also implemented the second option. Good answer :)

Comment: do you mean by option one call it in onwindowfocuschanged ?

Comment: Yuck, Android development is truly horrendous sometimes.

Comment: Very nice, cover most of my problems

Comment: When a Dialog or a Spinner shows, it has its own Window, so setSystemUiVisilityMode of Activity has no effect and Navigation UI still shows.

Comment: Has to be the 3 options :D

Answer (score 19):

I had the same problem, and I solved it with a simple workaround. Even though I couldn't find the theoretical reason of this workaround, but it worked for me anyway.

It seems like when a volume button is pressed, the 'flags' related to the 'immersive mode' are cleared. And I think that's why the immersive mode is disabled and the immersive mode is not restored automatically.

Therefore, I tried to set the 'flags' after pressing the volume button with 'runnable' object.

So, it works like this:

*immersive mode -> volume button pressed(flags cleared) -> 500ms later, the runnable object sets the flags again -> immersive mode restored*

**1. First, define the runnable object to set the flags**

```
private Runnable decor_view_settings = new Runnable()
{
    public void run() 
    {
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
    }
};
```

**2. Post the runnable object with some delay to a handler when a volume button is pressed**

```
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
```

...

```
@Override 
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
{
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
    {
        finish();
    }
    else if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP)
    {
        mHandler.postDelayed(decor_view_settings, 500);
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

I just delayed it for 500ms with no reason, it's not important.

**3. The basic code for immersive mode with runnable object**

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) 
{
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

    if(hasFocus) 
    {
        mHandler.post(decor_view_settings);
    }
}
```

It worked perfectly on my app.

So, when I press a volume button, the immersive mode is disabled and the volume rocker pops up.

after a few seconds, the volume rocker disappears and so does the status bar and the navigation bar.

Hope this work for you.

Comment: I had problem even with this "delayed" fix when switching between apps. Calling setSystemUiVisibility twice helped me: without SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY and then again with SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY. More details: http://vitiy.info/small-guide-how-to-support-immersive-mode-under-android-4-4/

Comment: Wow, this actually did the trick. The dismiss of the keyboard would not always get rid of the keyboard for us. And waiting for change notice was slightly more affective but still there is some sort of race condition on the older devices, but just hooking into visibility change got rid of the navigation bar when it was time to hid it. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. I'm displaying the ImageView's Bitmap to fullscreen in a new fragment when clicked. However, a status-bar sized blank space appeared at the bottom after fullscreen. Using View#post(Runnable) in onCreateView() works for me.

Comment: This solution is really working and should be the accepted answer! Thanks for the awesome work