# Return to immersive mode after closing the keyboard on Android

Tags: android, keyboard, android-4.4-kitkat

I added the immersive mode into my app. Here is the code :

```
 @Override
 public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
     super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
     if (hasFocus)
     {
         getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                 | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                 | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                 | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                 | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                 | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
     }
 }
```

But if I type on the keyboard and I close it (with the back button, by clicking on the screen), the navigation bar stays displayed, I need to reduce/reopen the app to get back the immersive mode.

How can I return to immersive mode after closing the keyboard ?

**EDIT :** It's a Cordova app

Comment: Did you found how to fix this problem?

Comment: No I didn't :/. Do you have a solution ?

Answer (score 2):

I used handlers to detect user inactivity and hide system ui thereafter. It automatically detect if user is not interacting on screen then auto hide system UI after 5 seconds

```
//Declare handler
private var timeoutHandler: Handler? = null
private var interactionTimeoutRunnable: Runnable? = null
```

In onCreate()

```
  @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
. . .

       //Initialise handler
        timeoutHandler =  Handler();
        interactionTimeoutRunnable =  Runnable {
            // Handle Timeout stuffs here
            hideSystemUI()
        }

        //start countdown
        startHandler()

. . .
```

Method to handle focus change

```
    override fun onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus: Boolean) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus)
        if (hasFocus) hideSystemUI()
    }
```

Hide system Ui

```
    private fun hideSystemUI() {
        // Enables regular immersive mode.
        // For "lean back" mode, remove SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE.
        // Or for "sticky immersive," replace it with SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
        window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = (View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE
                // Set the content to appear under the system bars so that the
                // content doesn't resize when the system bars hide and show.
                or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                // Hide the nav bar and status bar
                or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
    }


    // Shows the system bars by removing all the flags
// except for the ones that make the content appear under the system bars.
    private fun showSystemUI() {
        window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = (View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN)
    }



// reset handler on user interaction
override fun onUserInteraction() {
    super.onUserInteraction()
    resetHandler()
}

//restart countdown
fun resetHandler() {
    timeoutHandler!!.removeCallbacks(interactionTimeoutRunnable);
    timeoutHandler!!.postDelayed(interactionTimeoutRunnable, 5*1000); //for 10 second

}

// start countdown
fun startHandler() {
    timeoutHandler!!.postDelayed(interactionTimeoutRunnable, 5*1000); //for 10 second
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This theme: [Immersive mode navigation becomes sticky after volume press or minimise-restore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21164836/immersive-mode-navigation-becomes-sticky-after-volume-press-or-minimise-restore) covers similar question.

The "delayed" solution proposed there should work in your case.

I stumbled on the same problem and also problem that when you switch between apps nav bar also stays not hidden. I wrote some kind of guide how i solved this problem to keep things together: http://vitiy.info/small-guide-how-to-support-immersive-mode-under-android-4-4/

In short: i combined "delayed handlers" with this:

```
public void restoreTransparentBars()
{
    if (isApplicationInImmersiveMode)
        try {
            Window w = activity.getWindow();
            w.getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    );

            w.getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);

    } catch (Exception e) {}
}
```

Comment: It's working but when the keyboard is active, I can't scroll on the page :/

Comment: Somehow, the Fullscreen themes prevent the ScrollViews from scrolling when the SoftKeyboard is visible (under 4.4). Choose a theme, that is not fullscreen in manifest.xml, e.g.:
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light.NoActionBar"

Answer (score 1):

Not the best solution but defiantly the most simple and worked for me.

Try this :

```
final Handler forceImmersive = new Handler();
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            // Enables regular immersive mode.
            // For "lean back" mode, remove SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE.
            // Or for "sticky immersive," replace it with SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
            View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
            decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                            // Set the content to appear under the system bars so that the
                            // content doesn't resize when the system bars hide and show.
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                            // Hide the nav bar and status bar
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

            forceImmersive.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
    };

    forceImmersive.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/5993196/772428

You need to re-enable immersion mode on the back press. Here's the code code from that post.

```
public class EditTextBackEvent extends EditText {

    private EditTextImeBackListener mOnImeBack;

    public EditTextBackEvent(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public EditTextBackEvent(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public EditTextBackEvent(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyPreIme(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
       if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            if (mOnImeBack != null) mOnImeBack.onImeBack(this, this.getText().toString());
        }
        return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
    }

    public void setOnEditTextImeBackListener(EditTextImeBackListener listener) {
        mOnImeBack = listener;
    }

    public interface EditTextImeBackListener {
       public abstract void onImeBack(EditTextBackEvent ctrl, String text);
    }

}
```

Comment: I solved the problem using @Victor Laskin's solution. But now I can't scroll my page to see what is behind the keyboard.

Comment: By default the system guesses weather you want adjustpan or adjustsize for an activity. My guess is it is using adjustpan. In your Manifest within the said activity add the following `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21278040/4247554). I've searched for over 3 hours and this solution worked well. I hope it'll be useful.

Comment: Link-only answers are deprecated.