# Hiding on screen home and back buttons after soft keyboard goes unvisible

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I can hide on screen home and back buttons like this:

```
@Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        this.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        this.getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);)
    }
```

and same as onResume. But when my app opens the soft keyboard the buttons comes again and doesn't disappear after keyboard closes. I want home and back buttons to be invisible after soft keyboard is hidden. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Return to immersive mode after closing the keyboard on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23456144/return-to-immersive-mode-after-closing-the-keyboard-on-android)

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use a workaround solution for that, you can listen to the soft keyboard dismissing and then when dismissed try to set these flags again.

To listen to the keyboard dismissing([got it from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4737265/1638739))and then set the flags again, so the complete solution would be :

```
final View activityRootView = findViewById(R.id.activityRoot);
activityRootView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        int heightDiff = activityRootView.getRootView().getHeight() - activityRootView.getHeight();
        if (heightDiff > 100) { // if more than 100 pixels, its probably a keyboard...
                this.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
                this.getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);)
        }
     }
});
```