# In android, hide status bar and navigation bar but show action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, statusbar, navigationbar

I am trying to hide status and navigation bar but show action bar.

```
class MyActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                |  View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

This code works well. But if I press [VOLUME UP], [VOLUME DOWN] or [POWER], status bar and navigation bar appears.

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

I omit `decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);` and code above. Status bar disappears and does not appear when pressing [VOLUME UP], [VOLUME DOWN] or [POWER]. But navigation bar does NOT disappear.

When I press [VOLUME UP], [VOLUME DOWN] or [POWER],
how can I get rid of status bar and navigation bar?
And how can I leave action bar?

Comment: When I wrote this post, I could not find. But I have found a like instance. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21164836/immersive-mode-navigation-becomes-sticky-after-volume-press-or-minimise-restore/21278040#21278040

Comment: The way above works well. But I found a mistake.   1. Press [Volume Up] or [Volume Down].   2. Volume control appears.   3. Swipe from top to down before volume control disappears.   4. Navigation bar appears.   5. This Navigation bar does NOT disappear.   I think that it is almost certain that I use code like `getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);`.