# Android Fragment - Hide permanentrly navigation Bar opening BottomSheetFrag or always

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm working on a full Landscape project. I need all the time to hide manually Navigation Bar. Opening new fragment all work perfectly calling following util on onResume method:

```
        fun systemUiVisibility(activity: Activity) {
        activity.window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = (
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE
                        or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                        or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                )
        activity.window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON)
    }
```

When I open several items, such as Bottom sheet Fragment and others, the navigation bar is displayed again.
Is there any way to permanently hide it anywhere?

Comment: are you calling in onWindowFocusChanged and onCreate before super.onCreate?

Comment: No I don't. write the answer below :-)

Comment: it may be duplicate [first link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21164836/immersive-mode-navigation-becomes-sticky-after-volume-press-or-minimise-restore) and  [second link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21724420/how-to-hide-navigation-bar-permanently-in-android-activity)

Comment: it's not duplicate. Opening BottomSHeetFragment don't work

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was enough to override these two methods:

```
override fun onResume()
{
    super.onResume()
    window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
}

override fun onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus: Boolean)
{
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus)
    window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
}
```

but I am not sure if it will protect You from every scenario.

Comment: That's not help me. Opening BottomSheetFragment Navigation Bar is always visible